# Dart-Polymer 1.0 - How to align paper-fab horizontally?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I don't know if I'm missing something or if this is a bug, paper-fab buttons always "force a new line". So, I can't get several paper-fab buttons aligned horizontally. I have tried `<span>ing` them:

```
<span>
  <paper-fab mini icon='arrow-forward' on-click='onClickForward'></paper-fab>
  <paper-fab mini icon='arrow-backward' on-click='onClickBackward'></paper-fab>
</span>
```

and they are stacked vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `display` to `inline-block`

```
<style>
  paper-fab {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```